# Настройка асемблера под Visual Studio 6.0

Tags: windows, ассемблер, visual-studio

Учусь по специальности разработка програмного обеспечения и вот мне стукнуло в голову, что нужно бы разобраться как програмировать  на Асемблере. А вот как припихнуть к вижуал студио 6 сопрягаемые файлы-незнаю. Итак задача на сегодня такова...

У меня есть: Visual Studio 6.0, ollydbg и MASM 615. Ах да... и ещё вопрос... что такое irvine32.inc, где найти и как за ним ухаживать? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть очень хорошая [статья](http://wasm.ru/article.php?article=1005002), в ней всё детально описано:  Успехов!

Comment: спасибо, о великий человек ^_^

Answer (score 0):

VS 2010 встроенный ассемблер есть, кодить можно, отладчик тоже встроенный. И ассемблер. )

Answer (score 0):

Про сопряжение Visual Studio и MASM можно посмотреть здесь: [Getting Started](http://kipirvine.com/asm/gettingStartedVS2010/index.htm#batch) with MASM and Visual Studio 2010.

Заголовок и библиотека irvine - это (если не ошибаюсь) исходники, которые поставлялись вместе с книгой "Язык ассемблера для процессоров Intel" К.Ирвин. Думаю, их можно найти в сети.

Comment: с irvine32.inc уже разобралась, спасибо^_^

но у меня стоит 6.0..как не странно но я уже привыкла, да и на парах мы используем 6.0 и как-то устанавливать на старенький компьютер с 512Мб оперативки и с 60 ГБ жёстким не очень хочеться)..
а по ссылке как я понимаю к 2010 инструкция подключения?)